# If I can watch an editor putting my characters on the screen veeeeery slowly - how do you call that?

Tags: eclipse, editor, performance, keystroke

I'm using Eclipse and sometimes it's reacting for no apparent reason extreamly slowly to my keystrokes. Like it's putting one character per second on my screen.

Now I wanted to search for this on Google but couldn't think of a propper label/word/phrase/expression to refer to this effect.

What's your suggestion?

Best

Raffael

Comment: "my editor is on a trip"? :-)

Comment: jokes aside, I see no need for special terms. [This simple search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Eclipse+editor+displaying+characters+very+slowly) seems to turn up relevant stuff.

Comment: Oho, sometimes even 'Let me google that for you' answers are helpful. That's nice :-)

Comment: I don't want people to google for me, I was asking for a word ... in times of google all you need is the right words to solve nearly any problem. "typing lag" ... good one

Comment: It's not what you asked for, but I found a solution for this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9059880/703693

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google suggestions came up with:

[eclipse typing lag](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=eclipse+typing+lag)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change java version and heap size in eclipse.ini

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
- xmx1024m (http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F)
```

All of the editors are slow or just some of them?

Answer (score 0):

Aaaah ... "typing lag" ... that sounds great! I was thinking of another term though, but maybe I am comfusing something.

Though meanwhile I narrowed down the problem and it is related to having lots of HTML-Code and PHP intermingled. I guess it's some issue connected with the syntax-highliting-feature, as this fellow is beahaving strangely at times.

Best